# SAS profile-likelihood confidence intervals and p-values - why is there a discrepancy?

Tags: confidence-interval, p-value, sas, profile-likelihood

Using Firth's penalized likelihood method in logistic regression, why can you get a p-value of <.05 when the confidence interval for the estimate includes 1?

code:

```
PROC LOGISTIC DATA=model PLOTS(ONLY)=effectplot OUTMODEL=fq2;  
    MODEL outcome (EVENT='1')=  variable1 variable2 /FIRTH CLODDS=pl CLPARM=pl;
    OUTPUT OUT=estimated PREDICTED=estprob L=lower95 u=upper95 STDRESDEV=res;  
RUN;
```

Under SAS output titled "Analysis of Penalized Maximum Likelihood Estimates", my p-value for `variable1` is `0.0464`, but my 95% confidence limit under "Odds Ratio Estimates and Profile-Likelihood Confidence Intervals" is `0.39-1.041`. How is this possible?

ETA: It looks like SAS doesn't calculate p-values associated with the penalized-likelihood ratio tests. A macro available [here] (http://cemsiis.meduniwien.ac.at/en/kb/science-research/software/statistical-software/fllogistf/) provides a different corresponding p-value (that looks correct).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because a) It is pretty specific to SAS b) The OP answered it and c) It appears that more recent versions of SAS correct the problem.